# Meaning of horizontal bar in old formula (paranthesis?)

Tags: notation, correlation

When reading an old paper from 1921* I find formulas like:

$\rho + \frac{\rho(1- \rho^2)}{2\overline{n - 1}} \big( 1+  \frac{9 - 14\rho^2}{6\overline{n-1}} \big)$

which is said to be the median of the estimated sample correlation, $r$.

**What is the meaning of the horizontal bar above (n - 1)?**

My best guess is that it is an old alternative notation for paranthesis but I am not able to find any real justification for this assumption. The paper also include expressions such as:

$2 \overline{s-1}r = \overline{s-2}+s \tanh(z - \phi)$
where the need of paranthesis around $s-1$ can be questioned.

If there where complex numbers involved I guess it could also be the complex conjugate but that does not really make sense here.

*R A Fisher "On the probable error of a coefficient of correlation deduced from a small samlpe", Metron 1921,

Comment: Usually, $\overline x= \frac 1 n \Sigma x_i$ is the *sample mean*; see R.A.Fisher (1915), [page 65](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring05/sta215/lec/Fish1915.pdf).

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I do not think that is the meaning in this case since $n - 1$ does not relate to a random variable but to the sample size itself.

Answer (score -2):

The horizontal bar is called a vinculum and is an alternative to brackets. See Wikipedia and Jeff Miller.

Comment: The OP was talking about the bar over the arguments, not the vinculum, FYI.

Comment: It isn't clear what Wikipedia information you have in mind, perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol))?  In any case Markdown allows you to embed links in your post conveniently.

Comment: Please edit your very terse Answer to amplify the meaning.  I'm sure it is very clear to you (you are agreeing with the OP's "best guess"), but the Math.SE goal is to add useful content for learning math, not "fewest words".